# What is easy way to draw this lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used div tag for line but i need easy way for this .
I only know about div tag for this if you have another solution so please help me

```css
#line{
background-color:black;
height:1px;
width:50px;
margin-top:50px;
margin-left:50px;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="line">
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `svg` for this

```html
<svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>
```

1. The x1 attribute defines the start of the line on the x-axis
2. The y1 attribute defines the start of the line on the y-axis
3. The x2 attribute defines the end of the line on the x-axis
4. The y2 attribute defines the end of the line on the y-axis

For more info:https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_line.asp

Comment: Thanks this is useful for me but how can draw that bend line (In image 2 line)?

Comment: define your ```x``` and ```y``` coordinates using multiple ```<line>``` attribute inside ```svg``` tag

Answer (score 1):

you can use hr tag for line as well like

```
<hr id="line">

#line{
     width:5px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.line{
width: 150px;
border: 1px solid coral;
}
```

```html
        <hr class="line" />
        
        
        
        <div class="line"></div>
```